# Restrict input string length in argparse add_argument

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I want to add an argument of type string but restrict the length of the string to 1.

```
   group.add_argument(
        "--test_param",
        dest="test_param",
        type=str,
        required=True,
        default=None,
    )
```

Is there any way I can do it here without having to raise an error by checking `len(test_param)` later?

Comment: A custom `type` function is required; not that there's anything wrong with testing after parsing.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a `lambda` function in `type`

**Ex:**

```
import argparse

group = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Data.')
group.add_argument( 
        "--test_param",
        dest="test_param",
        type=lambda x: x if x.isalpha() and len(x) <=1 else False,   #Sample Function
        required=True,
        default=None,
    )

args = group.parse_args()
value = getattr(args, 'test_param')
if value:
    print(value)
else:
    print("error!!!")
```

**Output:**

```
python sample.py --test_param fddd  #->>error!!
python sample.py --test_param f     #->>f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the `type` parameter of `add_argument`.  The recommended way is to raise an exception during the type check:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

def len_gt_0(s):
    if len(s) > 0:
        return s
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Value must have length greater than 0")

parser.add_argument("--foo", type=len_gt_0, required=True)

opts = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

print(f"{ opts.foo = }")
```

Output:

```
$ python3.8 /tmp/foo.py  --foo=abc
opts.foo = 'abc'

$ python3.8 /tmp/foo.py  --foo=
usage: foo.py [-h] --foo FOO
foo.py: error: argument --foo: Value must have length greater than 0

$ python3.8 /tmp/foo.py  
usage: foo.py [-h] --foo FOO
foo.py: error: the following arguments are required: --foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the choices argument available while adding a argument for example in my code i just want to select from 1 or 2. I used the following snippet as follows:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "report",
    type=int,
    metavar="[report #]",
    help="1. for Annual Max/Min Temperature 2. for Hottest day of each year",
    choices=[1, 2]

)
```

it will restrict the input from these choices only and will show the error result if you have given out of these choices like this:

```
usage: [report#] [data_dir]

[report #]
1 for Annual Max/Min Temperature
2 for Hottest day of each year
            
[data_dir]
Directory containing weather data files
        
main.py: error: argument [report #]: invalid choice: 3 (choose from 1, 2)
```

If you don't want to add the choices you can use lamda or a function for validating the data. You can get help from my example below:

```
parser.add_argument(
        "data_dir",
        type=check_directory_availability,
        metavar="[data_directory]",
        help="Directory containing weather data files",
    )
def check_directory_availability(dir_name):

    if not os.path.isdir(dir_name):
        raise NotADirectoryError("Provided directory name doesn't exists")
    return dir_name
```

Hope so it may help you.

Comment: But that would require me to include the list of all possible single character strings in choices, which is rather cumbersome.

Comment: I have added the answer of this question. You can see that too.